# Add different text to the last line of a string - C# LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I want to take an input string and add `" ' + "` to the end of each line *except the last line*, on the last line I want to add `" ' ; "`

The following allows me to add `" ' + "` to *every* line:

```
string[] outputArr = outputRaw
  .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)      
  .Select((stringval, stringindex) => "'" + stringval + " ' + ") 
  .ToArray();

this.Output = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputArr);
```

Can this be adjusted to identify the last line and add different characters?

Comment: Side note : when you "+" a string, a new string is created each time and memory is "abused" that way. Recommend using StringBuilder to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest moving `" + "` from `Select` into `Join`: we join lines with `" + \r\n"` and, finally, add `";"` to the end:

```
string[] outputArr = outputRaw
   .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
   .Select((stringval, stringindex) => $"'{stringval}'")
   .ToArray();

this.Output = String.Join(" + " + Environment.NewLine, outputArr) + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are after is

```
string[] outputArr = outputRaw
   .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
   .Select((stringval, stringindex) => "'" + stringval + " '")                                
   .ToArray();

this.Output = String.Join($" + {Environment.NewLine}", outputArr) + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the new lines :

```
this.Output = "'" + outputRaw.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ' + " + Environment.NewLine + "'") + " ' ; ";
```